# Android emulator hangs without any error message on windows 7

Tags: android, emulation

** NOTE: I no longer use this environment so there is no way for me to test the answers and accept one. I'm sorry. **

I know that there are lots of answers to my question but all of them ask for the erros in the logs messages and I fail to see any error in my logs.

I'm trying to run emulator.exe in a windows 7.(1)

I tried to run the emulator with vervose. The log is below and, theoretically the most significant messages are the last although I fail to see any significance to them all:

```
C:\Users\ASUS\workspace\Android\android-sdk\tools>emulator.exe -avd 22 -verbose
emulator: found SDK root at C:\Users\ASUS\workspace\Android\android-sdk
emulator: root virtual device file at C:\Users\ASUS\.android/avd/22.ini
emulator: virtual device content at C:\Users\ASUS\.android\avd\22.avd
emulator: virtual device config file: C:\Users\ASUS\.android\avd\22.avd/config.ini
emulator:     locking user data image at C:\Users\ASUS\.android\avd\22.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator:     locking cache image at C:\Users\ASUS\.android\avd\22.avd/cache.img
emulator:     locking SD Card image at C:\Users\ASUS\.android\avd\22.avd/sdcard.img
emulator: ignoring non-existing snapshots at C:\Users\ASUS\.android\avd\22.avd/snapshots.img: No such file or directory
emulator: found skin 'QVGA' in directory: C:\Users\ASUS\workspace\Android\android-sdk/platforms\android-8\skins
emulator: autoconfig: -skin QVGA
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir C:\Users\ASUS\workspace\Android\android-sdk/platforms\android-8\skins
emulator: keyset loaded from: C:\Users\ASUS\.android\default.keyset emulator: trying to load skin file 'C:\Users\ASUS\workspace\Android\android-sdk/platforms\android-8\skins/QVGA/layout'
emulator: skin network speed: 'full'
emulator: skin network delay: 'none'
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = "emulator.exe"
emulator: argv[01] = "-kernel"
emulator: argv[02] = "C:\Users\ASUS\workspace\Android\android-sdk/platforms\android-8\images\/kernel-qemu"
emulator: argv[03] = "-netspeed"
emulator: argv[04] = "full"
emulator: argv[05] = "-netdelay"
emulator: argv[06] = "none"
emulator: argv[07] = "-initrd"
emulator: argv[08] = "C:\Users\ASUS\workspace\Android\android-sdk/platforms\android-8\images\/ramdisk.img"
emulator: argv[09] = "-nand"
emulator: argv[10] = "system,size=0x4e00000,initfile=C:\Users\ASUS\workspace\Android\android-sdk/platforms\android-8\images\/system.img"
emulator: argv[11] = "-nand"
emulator: argv[12] = "userdata,size=0x4200000,file=C:\Users\ASUS\.android\avd\22.avd/userdata-qemu.img"
emulator: argv[13] = "-nand"
emulator: argv[14] = "cache,size=0x4200000,file=C:\Users\ASUS\.android\avd\22.avd/cache.img"
emulator: argv[15] = "-hda"
emulator: argv[16] = "C:\Users\ASUS\.android\avd\22.avd/sdcard.img"
emulator: argv[17] = "-loadvm"
emulator: argv[18] = "default-boot"
emulator: argv[19] = "-savevm-on-exit"
emulator: argv[20] = "default-boot"
emulator: argv[21] = "-serial"
emulator: argv[22] = "android-kmsg"
emulator: argv[23] = "-serial"
emulator: argv[24] = "android-qemud"
emulator: argv[25] = "-lcd-density"
emulator: argv[26] = "120"
emulator: argv[27] = "-append"
emulator: argv[28] = "qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.checkjni=1 android.qemud=ttyS1"
emulator: argv[29] = "-m"
emulator: argv[30] = "96"
emulator: argv[31] = "-android-avdname"
emulator: argv[32] = "22"
emulator: argv[33] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[34] = "C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\TMP4144. tmp"
Concatenated QEMU options:
 emulator.exe -kernel C:\Users\ASUS\workspace\Android\android-sdk/platforms\android-8\images\/kernel-qemu -netspeed full -netdelay none -initrd C:\Users\ASUS\workspace\Android\android-sdk/platforms\android-8\images\/ramdisk.img -nand system ,size=0x4e00000,initfile=C:\Users\ASUS\workspace\Android\android-sdk/platforms\android-8\images\/system.img -nand userdata,size=0x4200000,file=C:\Users\ASUS\.android\avd\22.avd/userdata-qemu.img -nand cache,size=0x4200000,file=C:\Users\ASUS\.android\avd\22.avd/cache.img -hda C:\Users\ASUS\.android\avd\22.avd/sdcard.img -loadvm default-boot -savevm-on-exit default-boot -serial android-kmsg -serial
android-qemud -lcd-density 120 -append qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.checkjni=1 android.qemud=ttyS1 -m 96 -android-avdname 22 -android-hw C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\TMP4144.tmp
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service emulator: mapping 'system' NAND image to C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Local\Temp\\AndroidEmulator\TMP4902.tmp
emulator: rounding devsize up to a full eraseunit, now 4e1e000

emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '24m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '120'
emulator: Trace file name is not set

emulator: control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
emulator: sent '0012host:emulator:5555' to ADB server
emulator: ping program: C:\Users\ASUS\workspace\Android\android-sdk\tools\ddms.bat
emulator: ping command: C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /C "C:\Users\ASUS\workspace\Android\android-sdk\tools\ddms.bat" ping emulator 10.0
goldfish_fb_get_pixel_format:167: display surface,pixel format:
  bits/pixel:  16
  bytes/pixel: 2
  depth:       16
  red:         bits=5 mask=0xf800 shift=11 max=0x1f
  green:       bits=6 mask=0x7e0 shift=5 max=0x3f
  blue:        bits=5 mask=0x1f shift=0 max=0x1f
  alpha:       bits=0 mask=0x0 shift=0 max=0x0
```

I am also attaching a screenshot with the look of the emulator when it hangs:
EDIT: Wops, I'm not able to attach screenshots, lack of reputation, sorry.
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/GH8fu.png

I let it "run" for more than 20 minutes and I tried like a dozen of times with the same results.

Any hint will be greatly apreciated. Thanks!

(1) Full specs of the computer are:
Windows 7.
1.66Ghz Intel Atom x2 (32b)
2 GB ram

Comment: Don't have an answer, but curious as to why you are running the emulator from DOS command prompt. Do you really need this level of conrtol. Have you tried using Eclipse to launch the emulator - or did that fail and now you are delving into DOS script? Am using Windows-7 myself, did a clean install of Eclipse adn never had any problems adn never had to delve into DOS. Oliver

Comment: I was not able to make the emulator work so I wanted a more detailed log. Not that it helped much dough.

Comment: On Linux I get the exact same behavior - 3 years later.  These problems have never been addressed/fixed by Google.  You can try different api-levels and kernels until maybe one works, and next month, Google will release another set, of which another random subset are broken, including ones that worked before.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar issue when trying to launch API 15 x86 in ubuntu running on an AMD phenom processor. The API 19 x86 was booting fine and API 12 arm was too. API 12 x86 is not available. I kept trying to boot the API 15 x86 and it would hang at the same `goldfish_fb_pixel_format:...`.

My solution was to use API 15 arm (armeabi-v7a) rather than x86. It seems to be working now.

The problem could be my system configuration. I am on an older AMD chipset and the SSSE3 is not available. It may have been a bad system image download: I was having such a slow network connection downloading the API 15 x86 and, perhaps, it was somehow downloading in error? I doubt it.. but possible. When I downloaded the API 15 arm, it was nice and quick. In either case, I am content now that I have something to test API 15.

There are two places to delete downloaded images.

1. `~/Android/system-images/android-<version>/default/<platform>`
2. `~/.android/avd/<the_avd_you_created>.avd`

Make sure to delete both directories first and then restart the AVD manager, if you want to try re-downloading.

Comment: Hi JJ Stiff. Sorry but I don't have that development environment anymore so I can not check your answer. Thanks for taking the time to answer though